# How to send multiple input values through Ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass multiple input values through Ajax jquery but for some unknown reason, it is not working.

For example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control invoice_item_name" name="invoice_item_name">
<input type="text" class="form-control invoice_item_name" name="invoice_item_name">
```

jQuery and Ajax

```
    $('.invoice_item_name').each(function(){
        var invoice_item_name = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/some-php.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {invoice_item_name:invoice_item_name) {
            $('.error_message').html(add_invoice_result);
        }
    });
```

some-php.php file

```
$invoice_item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['invoice_item_name']);

$insert_order_item = "insert into invoice_order_item(order_item_name) values('$invoice_item_name')";
        
$insert_order_item_query = mysqli_query($connection,$insert_order_item);
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? and I wrapped the "INSERT INTO" query in "for loop". So each item_name stored in the new row.

Comment: `var invoice_item_name = $(this).val();` simply overwrites the variable each time and will only hold the last value.

Comment: Please note that the way you're writing your query is unsafe, as it's still open to SQL injection, because [escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe enough. You should switch to [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent it.

Comment: So what is the solution? By the way, it is also throwing this error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" @El_Vanja

Comment: Yeah, I know! This is just for practice! @El_Vanja

Comment: The solution would be to build an array.

Comment: var invoice_item_name = new Array();
$('.invoice_item_name').each(function() {
   invoice_item_name.push($(this).val());
}); @El_Vanja

Comment: I think this would do the job! @El_Vanja

Comment: It should, yes.

Comment: The issue has been resloved! Thank you @El_Vanja

Answer (score 0):

As @EL_vanja mentioned in the comment section that, var invoice_item_name = $(this).val(); simply overwrites the variable each time and will only hold the last value.

The solution was to build an array.

`var invoice_item_name = new Array(); $('.invoice_item_name').each(function() { invoice_item_name.push($(this).val()); });`